# Validate CSS in C#

Tags: css, escaping, xss

I have a web app which generates HTML-code. The user can enter some CSS-code, which is automatically inserted inside of a `<style></style>` tag.

Now a malicious user could enter something like `</style><script>maliciousFunction();</script><style>` here. But if I simply escape the whole input, then also valid CSS is escaped (like braces for example) and the style doesn't work anymore.

What would be the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping is not the best option, as all these characters may naturally exist in css code `( < ' " : ; > )`, thus I believe better option would be using some parser that will parse and clean the code to pure css leaving all not-understandable mess behind, one that I found: https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be a good solution. Just a little curiousity I discovered when parsing code with ExCSS: the parser always adds '{ }' at the end of the output, any idea what's the reason for this behaviour?